# Left-aligned tabs in GWT

Tags: gwt, tabs

I have a project in which I need a way to display essentially a list of tabs, each with their own content pages, down the left side of the page. I'm using TabLayoutPanels elsewhere to good effect, but after looking at how they are constructed it seems like it would be quite a bit of work to undo Google's carefully constructed layout and get it to work in any other orientation than top-aligned.

This doesn't seem like it would be an uncommon layout, so does anyone know of a successful implementation of this kind of container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best you can do is use `DeckPanel`, and make your custom tab controls to switch visible widget in that `DeckPanel`.

Comment: Thanks, forgot about the DeckPanel! That will work nicely, since my biggest concern with a custom solution was hiding/showing widgets in a cross-browser-friendly manner.

Comment: Okay, got a working solution in place. Just a hint for anyone attempting to do the same thing: Deriving widgets like this one from ResizeComposite saves you from a lot of pain and suffering! Do it!